# html dropdown containing list python output

Tags: python, node.js, html

I am trying to use the list from my python output into a dropdown menu in an HTML form.

I have a website built in HTML/ CCS, a server with nodeJS, and several scripts i want to use in python3.

I currently have no idea how to integrate the python output to the dropdown. Do i need to use Javascript or my node server is enough?

My HTML form

```
 <form action="/LUNProvisionning" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>LUN Provisionning</legend>
      <br />
      <label>Choix du serveur : </label>
      <select id="serveur" name="serveur">
      # put python output here!! 
      <option value="1">no serveurs</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <label>Volumétrie en Go 5 - 1000 : </label>
      <input type="number" min="5" max="1000" placeholder="500" name="volumetrie" required>
      <br />
      <label>Type de provisionning : </label>
      <select id="provisionning" name="type" required>
        <option value="Thin">Thin</option>
        <option value="Deco">Deco</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

python output:

```
SSD_r1
SSD_r5
SSD_r6
fs_cpg
CPG4S2
```

These need to be in the dropdown above.

I have a node server that i can show if it's relevant.

Thank you very much for your help.
Any informations or links, anything can help.

Comment: How are you receiving the python output? Do you have an api endpoint that you are calling?

Comment: i simply run python file arg1 arg2 arg3